# How to embed a view controller into a navigation view controller programmatically

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to embed my view controller into a navigation view controller so i get the navigation bar and all the other stuff like back buttons. I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is done like this:

```
// example ViewController
let myVC = UIViewController()

// create the NavigationController with my VC as root
let navCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
```

Comment: Will that give the nav bar

Comment: Yes. For the title, set myVC.title = “title text”.  You’ll get a back button when you push the next VC.